# Javascript Dynamically Change Object Values

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like this

```
var userobj = {
    user1: {
        firstName: 'abc',
        lastName: 'abc', 
        age: 29,
        address: {
            company: {
                location: 'xyz',
                city: 'xyz',
                street: 'xyz',
                city: 'xyz'
            },
            location: 'xyz',
            city: 'xyz',
            street: 'xyz',
            city: 'xyz'
        },
        payment: {
            visa: false,
            master: false,
            paypal: true
        },

    },

    user2: {
        firstName: 'abc',
        lastName: 'abc', 
        age: 29,
        address: {
            company: {
                location: 'xyz',
                city: 'xyz',
                street: 'xyz',
                city: 'xyz'
            },
            location: 'xyz',
            city: 'xyz',
            street: 'xyz',
            city: 'xyz'
        },
        payment: {
            visa: false,
            master: false,
            paypal: true
        }
    }
};
```

I want to write a function to change the data dynamically like this Funtkion

```
function updateUserData(userName, key, value) {
    userobj[userName][key] = value;
}
```

This works if  only to change the first level key

```
updateUserData('user1', 'firstName', 'David');
```

can someone tell me how I can change the function so that I can change key into other levels too? Perhaps with an array as parameter? Like this

```
updateUserData('user1', ['address', 'company', 'location'], 'David');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function updateUserData(userName, keys, value) {
    var obj = userobj[userName];

    for(var i=0; i<keys.length-1; i++){
        obj = obj[keys[i]];
    }

    obj[keys[i]] = value;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rPPK5/1/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I know to set a nested property is by providing a path to that property accompanied with a new value.

A simple implementation could be:

```
function ObjectWrapper (obj) {
    this.object = obj;
    this.pattern = new RegExp(/^[[a-z\._]]+$/i);

    // set a property at the given path
    this.setPropertyValue = function (path, value) {
        if (this.pattern.test(path)) {
            eval('this.object.' + path + '=' + JSON.stringify(value));
        }else{
            throw new Error('Malformed property path');
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var obj = {
    name: 'Bob',
    friends: {
        name: 'Joe'
    }
};

var wrapper = new ObjectWrapper(obj);
wrapper.setPropertyValue('friends.name', 'Rick');
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex of that implementation was wrong, now it working

```
function ObjectWrapper(obj) {
  this.object = obj;
  this.pattern = new RegExp(/^[[a-z\._]+$/i);

  // set a property at the given path
  this.setPropertyValue = (path, value) => {
    if (this.pattern.test(path)) {
      eval('this.object.' + path + '=' + JSON.stringify(value));
    } else {
      throw new Error('Malformed property path');
    }
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
var obj = {
    name: 'Bob',
    friends: {
        name: 'Joe'
    }
};

var wrapper = new ObjectWrapper(obj);
wrapper.setPropertyValue('friends.name', 'Rick');
```